# "Static" method design

Tags: go

I'm looking for advice on the best way to clean up the following structure. I know Go doesn't have static methods and it's usually [better to encapsulate functionality in a separate package](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/mKXyUoVT6m4). My struct types reference each other, and so cannot be declared in separate packages because of circular imports.

```
type Payment struct {
    User *User
}

type User struct {
    Payments *[]Payments
}

func (u *User) Get(id int) *User {
    // Returns the user with the given id 
}

func (p *Payment) Get(id int) *Payment {
    // Returns the payment with the given id 
}
```

But, if I want to load a user or payment, I'm just throwing away the receiver:

```
var u *User
user := u.Get(585)
```

I could namespace the functions themselves, which strikes me as unclean:

```
func GetUser(id int) *User {
    // Returns the user with the given id 
}

func GetPayment(id int) *Payment {
    // Returns the payment with the given id 
}
```

I would really like to be able to just call `.Get` or similar on the struct without writing the name of the struct in the function itself. What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`GetUser()` and `GetPayment()` strike me as perfectly clear and idiomatic.  I'm not sure what you find unclean about them.

Calling `.Get()` on a struct to return *another* struct is the thing that strikes me as very odd, unclear, and unidiomatic.

I think this might be a case of just sticking with the idiom and trusting that you'll get used to it.

Comment: Yes, I find `.Get()` on a struct that I'm throwing away even more unclean. To me `User.Get()` is cleanest; if `GetUser` is the closest approximation I can get, I'll take it.

Comment: @ash Yes, I believe it is the closest you can get, and the most idiomatic Go way to do it.

Comment: You can't create frameworks and libraries with GetUser and GetPayment

Answer (score 26):

Golang does not support constructors.

Use factory functions instead ([Effective Go reference](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals)). The convention is to use `New` prefix:

```
func NewUser(id int) *User {
    // Returns new User instance
}
```

The difference between constructor and factory function is that factory function is not "attached" to the `User` struct. It's a normal function that happen to return `User` while the Java/C++ like constructor is a method that modifies newly created `User` object in place.

Answer (score 17):

having a `Get` function is perfectly fine; it's not *unidiomatic* in any way.

`func (u *User) Get(id int) *User` doesn't make any sense, though, it should be `func (u *User) Get(id int) error`.  The one thing that you're missing is that you can define a method receiver on a pointer, and then inside of that method, dereference the pointer to overwrite what it points to.

Like this:

```
// Returns the user with the given id 
func (u *User) Get(id int) error {
    *u = User{ ... } // dereference the pointer and assign something to it
    return nil // or an error here
}
```

and if there was any problem, return an error.  Now you can say

```
type Getter interface {
    Get(int) error
}
```

and so any type that defines `Get(id)error` can be defined.  You would then use it like this:

```
u := new(User)
if err := u.Get(id); err != nil {
    // problem getting user
}
// everything is cool.
```

Comment: I this this semantics is more related to the usual meaning of `Load` than to the one of `Get.`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to call simulating an static method, despite the fact it isn't, is as follows:

```
package main
 
import "fmt"
 
type Manager struct {
}

func (m Manager) MyMethod(a float32, b float32) float32 {
    return 0.5 * a * b
}
 
func main() {
    fmt.Println((Manager).MyMethod(Manager{}, 15, 25))
}
```

But from my point of view, it is less understandable than placing this method in a separate package `manager`outside from class `Manager`

From comments, another alternative would be:

```
 fmt.Println(Manager{}.MyMethod(15, 25))
```

Finally with pointers:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Manager struct {
}

func (m *Manager) MyMethod(a float32, b float32) float32 {
    return 0.5 * a * b
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println((*Manager).MyMethod(&Manager{}, 15, 25))

    fmt.Println((&Manager{}).MyMethod(15, 25))
}
```

Comment: As a side note, `(Manager).MyMethod(Manager{}, 15, 25)` is overly lengthy way to call your method. It would be enough to just write `Manager{}.MyMethod(15, 25)`. Although `Manager{}` semantically means a new instance of `Manager`, the Golang compiler treat empty struct specially, and it should be able to optimize away the "object creation" completely. See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/GvFH47W9BVd) for your code rewritten by me.